# Php - Lost ressource socket in a stack Threaded

Tags: sockets, stack, connection, pthreads

I have 2 class, ListenUser class get new user and push in ReadSocket class the ressource socket of this new user.
The problem is when I pushed the new user in the stack, I lost automatically the ressource socket IN the stack but it's continue to works in ListenUser class.
How can I put a new user in the ReadSocket stack and keed the connection ?

ListenUser class code after receiving server socket

```
class ListenUser
{
    /*

    */
    public function         __construct($socket, $debug = false)
    {
        $this->socket = $socket
        $this->StackSocket = new StackSocket;  // class StackSocket extends Threaded {}
        $this->ReadSocket = new ReadSocket($this->StackSocket);
    }

    /*

    */
    public function         run()
    {
        while (true) {
            if (($user = socket_accept($this->socket)) !== false)
            {
                //
                $this->ReadSocket->synchronized(function($thread) {
                    if ($thread->statutThread == true) {
                        $thread->wait();
                    }
                    $thread->statutUsers = true;
                    $thread->notify();
                }, $this->ReadSocket);

                //
                $this->ReadSocket->synchronized(function($thread, $user) {
                    $thread->addUser($user); // Add user
                    $thread->statutUsers = false;
                    $thread->notify();
                }, $this->ReadSocket, $user);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And my ReadSocket class code

```
<?php

class ReadSocket extends Thread
{
    /*

    */
    public function         __construct($stack, $debug = false)
    {
        $this->stack = $stack;
    }

    /*

    */
    public function         run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            $this->synchronized(function($thread) {
                if ($thread->statutUsers == true) {
                    $thread->wait();
                }
                $thread->statutThread = true;
                $thread->notify();
            }, $this);
            $this->statutThread = false;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /*

    */
    public function         addUser($user)
    {
        print_r($user); // my ressource socket is ok
        $this->stack[] = $user; 
        print_r($this->stack[0]); // I lost ressource socket
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, socket (socket_create, socket_bind and socket_listen) was used/declared in no-thread class. So I extended to thread class and it's be ok :)